# How to set TransactTime in quickFix using Python to GMT format

Tags: python, quickfix

I'm relatively new to using `python` and `quickfix`, I want the transaction time for a message to be in UTC format so that the transact time looks like `YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.mmm`  so basically I want tag 60 to look like `2012-02-13-08:15:35.435` for example

I did the following code

```
newSingle.getHeader().setField(fix.Transacttime(time.gmtime()))
```

but I'm getting errors that doesn't match C/C++ prototypes

```
  newSingle.getHeader().setField(fix.TransactTime(time.gmtime()))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/quickfix.py", line 41959, in __init__
    quickfix.UtcTimeStampField.__init__(self, 60, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/quickfix.py", line 764, in __init__
    this = _quickfix.new_UtcTimeStampField(*args)
NotImplementedError: Wrong number of arguments for overloaded function 'new_UtcTimeStampField'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    FIX::UtcTimeStampField(int,UtcTimeStamp const &,bool)
    FIX::UtcTimeStampField(int,UtcTimeStamp const &)
    FIX::UtcTimeStampField(int,bool)
    FIX::UtcTimeStampField(int)
```

Any help as to how I can achieve the result I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Check how **Transacttime** is implemented in quickfix.And then check what time.gmtime() returns. That should give you the problem point.

Answer (score 4):

As `UtcTimeStamp` isn't supported in Python, I suggest setting the value manually.

```
newSingle.getHeader().setField(fix.StringField(60,(datetime.utcnow ().strftime ("%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f"))[:-3]))
```

Or you could also do like this.

```
transact_time = fix.TransactTime()
transact_time.setString('20160404-03:52:24.824')
newSingle.getHeader().setField(transact_time)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

## code

```
#imports
import quickfix
import quickfix50sp2

#code
...
newSingle = quickfix50sp2.NewOrderSingle()

t = quickfix.TransactTime()
t.setString(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])

newSingle.setField(t)
```

After this you will have complete the "tag 60" in the message.
Tri it in ipython a check it:

```
In[]: newSingle.toString()
Out[]: '8=FIXT.1.1\x019=37\x0135=D\x011128=9\x0160=20180603-18:19:51.428\x0110=091\x01'
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, rookie error, to answer my own question:

```
newSingle.getHeader().setField(fix.SendingTime(1))
```

This will do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fix.TransactionTime()` it creates the tag with the current time by default. For example:

```
In [68] : fix.TransactTime().getString()
Out[68] : '20160701-18:01:57'
```

If you want to set a custom timestamp:

```
In [135] : dnow = datetime.utcnow()

In [136] : dnow.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')
Out[136] : '20160701-18:23:33'

In [137] : tag = fix.TransactTime()

In [138] : tag.getString()
Out[138] : '20160701-18:23:46'

In [139] : tag.setString(dnow.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S'))

In [140] : tag.getString()
Out[140] : '20160701-18:23:33'
```

Note that `SendingTime` (52) and `TransactionTime` (60) are two different tags but their behavior is the same (i.e. you can apply the same logic to `SendingTime` as `TransactionTime` above).